# So after my python code runs, I enter input, the program just stops. Don't know what the logic error is

Tags: python, csv, parsing, reader, logic-error

I'm trying to create a simple parser for CSV files. I'm trying to use the easiest way to look through the parser to look for a value(row).

```
import csv
"""
with open('C:/MAIL07072021180029.csv', 'r') as file:
     proxy = csv.reader(file)
     for row in proxy:
         print(row[0])

"""

identifyingnumber = input("What is the number? ")

with open('C:/MAIL07072021180029.csv', 'r') as file:
    data = csv.reader(file)
    for row in data:
        if row[1] == (identifyingnumber):
            print(row)
```

After I run the code and I enter the proxy number(identifying number, the data in my excel). The program just stops? It's not printing the row.

Here is a sample data from my csv file:

```
Card Identifying Sequence
1873356
```

I printed out row 0 by taking out if, the row was printed successful, the identifying number.

Is this some kind logic error? I cannot figure this out.

Comment: Perhaps if you print each `row` you'll be able to see what it actually holds.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I thought I did print the rows

Comment: If you printed your rows you should be able to see what they contain and whether any of them has the thing you're looking for as an element. Take out the `if` constraint so your code just prints every row, and see what you are getting.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct separator? The csv module defaults to using a comma.

Comment: @sommervold separator?

Comment: @learnpython a separator is the character in a csv file that separates different data values. say you have a file with three columns `col1,col2,col3` The comma, known as the separator, is required so your program can know where one datavalue ends and a new begins. csv stands for 'comma separated values'.

Comment: @learnpython if you're using excel to make these files, it is not unlikely that they are separated by a semi-colon ';'. change `data = csv.reader(file)` to `data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=";")`.  to see which character to use, open your csv file in a normal text editor, like notepad.

Comment: It is an csv file, the row was printed out right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your csv file may not have the identifying number in it, in which case nothing will print out, because of your 'if' statement.  You could check for whether you ever found the number, and if so, break (if you don't want to check other rows for yet another instance of the number), and if not, print that you never found the number.

```
with open('C:/MAIL07072021180029.csv', 'r') as file:
    data = csv.reader(file)
    found = False
    for row in data:
        if row[1] == (identifyingnumber):
            print(row)
            found = True
            break    # if you don't want to look for more instances of identifyingnumber
    if not found:   # aka found == False
        print('I did not find any row[1] equal to', identifyingnumber)
```

I highly recommend Pandas for what you are trying to do.  Open the csv in Pandas and then check all rows at once for the value, instead of iterating through rows.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/MAIL07072021180029.csv')
col1 = df.columns[1]
dfi = df[df[col1] == identifyingnumber]
dfi = dfi.reset_index()
print(dfi['index'].tolist())        # there could be more than 1 row with the identifier
```

Edit to put everything together from our discussion in the comments:

```
file_list = ['C:/MAIL07072021180029.csv','C:/other_file.csv']
for f in file_list:
    with open(f, 'r') as file:
        data = csv.reader(file)
        found = False
        for row in data:
            if found:   # aka found == True - if any column found the value, break to stop iterating
                break
            for col in range(1, len(row)):   # start at 1 to skip col 0
                if row[col] == identifyingnumber:  # (identifyingnumber) is a tuple(), you probably don't want that
                    print(row)
                    found = True
                    break    # if you don't want to look for more instances of identifyingnumber
        if not found:   # aka found == False
            print('I did not find any row[1] equal to', identifyingnumber)
```

Comment: Thank you! One last thing, I can modify the code to include multiple input files right? I mean to search through like 10 different files.

Comment: Certainly!  For example, you can get a list of all files in a directory, or (not as ideal) manually specify every file in a list, then iterate through the list and keep the rest of the code the same:  for f in file_list:   with open(f, 'r') as file: ...  Let me know if you need help with that part.

Comment: also I think maybe there's bug in the code or my logic is wrong, but it says nothing returend when I put in the first row, even though the value is there.

Comment: Can you add a loop to search through each row? Row 0 is identifier, and row 1 is data. Something is wrong

Comment: Yes, you can iterate through each col within in each row:  for row in data:  for col in row[1:]:  (assuming you want to skip col 0)  if row[col] == identifyingnumber.  Also, I just noticed that you have () around identifyingnumber and you probably do not want that -- it will check whether the cell has a tuple() with identifyingnumber in it, rather than checking for the number.  Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Can you please remodify your answer if you have time? Later tonight I will study the code and logic for Python.

Comment: Sure, see the edited section at the end of the answer

Comment: Also the part you edited out, where do I put the path of the file?

Comment: See the revised end of the edited answer, file_list = ['C:/MAIL07072021180029.csv','C:/other_file.csv']

Comment: hey anyway I can contact you? I'm having problem with my script I can't explain.

Comment: Hey sorry one more question, after I run the code, I got a new error:

Comment: line 15, in <module>
    if row[col] == proxynumber:  # (proxynumber) is a tuple(), you probably don't want that
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Oh, sorry, col is a string so that's why are are getting that error.  I was thinking that the row was in Pandas rather than a csv file.  Assuming you don't want to check col 0, use for col in range(1, len(row)), to test columns from 1 to however many there are.  I'll edit the answer too.

Comment: ughh anyway you can email me, gethbownow at gmail, it's a temporary account I literally created. I don't want keep posting comment here and wait for another 90minuts to post questoins.